# DIV/SPAN tag not displaying full on the last of GRID

Tags: css, angular, angular8

Using Kendo Grid on Angular8. I have code to display a DIV when hovering on another DIV. Its template which gets repeated on every row on the grid. It works and displays good on all the rows except the last row, where the most part of DIV hiding insidethe grid.

tried to change Display and position paramters of style. Tried most of the all combinations.

CODE

```
    <span *ngIf="showDownloadDropdown && dataItem.DOC_ID" class="dropdown">
                                <span>
                                    <i style="padding-right: 3px; color: lightslategray;cursor: pointer" class="fa fa-download"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="dropdown-content">
                                    <p *ngFor="let item of downloadDropdownItems" (click)="downloadDropdownHandler(dataItem,item.Code);" class="k-block k-button k-flat" style="background-color: #06446C; color: #06446C;">{{item.Description}}</p>
                                </span>
                            </span>
```

First DIV

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: contents;
}
```

style of DIV which gets displayed like sub-menu

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 3px 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: lightblue;
```

Comment: It will be great if you can create a stackblitz so we can play with it

Comment: for some security reasons the stackblitz wont open at my work. sorry.

Comment: Any alternatives can be opened? jsfiddle, codepen, jsbin, plunker, codesandbox

Comment: I did a workaround by modiying the size of the sub-menu and moved the top to align with the row. so now its actually aligned to the right of the field with the row. Sorry code publishing tools are blocked here. thanks for your response.